# Cannot delete locked column or row on protected worksheet (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote VBA code to hide formulas. How can I let user to delete columns, rows that contain formulas? (Excel 2019)
This code doesn't work..

```
    Sub Protect()
    Cells.Select
        Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23).Select 
        Selection.Locked = True
        Selection.FormulaHidden = True
            
       ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="xxx", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:= _
            False, AllowDeletingColumns:=True, _
            AllowDeletingRows:=True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to the board.   _This code doesn't work_ isn't very helpful in identifying what part of the code doesn't work.  Have a read of [mcve].  That said - you can't delete those columns because you've locked the cells with formula - `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 23).Locked = True`.

Comment: @Darren Bartrup-Cook Can I edit my question? :)

Comment: Yes - there's an edit button just below the Excel and VBA tags at the bottom of your post.

Comment: I just unlocked cells. Everythig ok now :) (Thanks, Darren)